# How to ssh from one server to multiple server and switch to root and then change root password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, expect

From server **A**, i want to ssh multiple server using a non root user as direct root login is disabled to all server.

1. then i need to **su -** to switch to root
2. perform some normal operations, like changing directory, listing file etc.
3. and at the end change the root password using **passwd** command

I have **expect** installed on all servers and i am able to ssh from server **A** to any of the other servers but stuck in switching to root user and performing other operations as listed above.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@ip<<'ENDSSH'
./su2root
#random operations
pwd
whoami
#random operations
./changepass
ENDSSH
```

su2root

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn su -
set password "rootpass"
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r"
```

changepass

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set newpassword "newrootpass"
spawn passwd 
expect "*assword*"
send "$newpassword\r"
expect "*assword*"
send "$newpassword\r"
expect eof
exit 0
```

expecting to accomplish it using shell scripting only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question should show what you have unsuccessfully tried, and not just request the community to solve your issue.
That said, you may want to look at running expect locally and spawning an ssh session to each system.
Or better yet, use Ansible. :)

Comment: @Deathgrip edited now :)

Comment: Not just how what you tried, but _isolate a narrow, specific issue_ and focus the question about that issue. The overall thing you're trying to accomplish is not an issue; the technical problem that stopped you from doing that thing successfully on your own is an issue.

Comment: Anyhow -- you see how you needed to use a heredoc to feed commands to ssh? `su2root` doesn't work to change _what user_ later commands in the script that started it run as for the same reason ssh doesn't change what host later commands run on: Just as ssh has to exit before the next command is started, so does `su2root`. (If you made `su2root` pass its stdin through to the child process it starts, then you could use a heredoc for it just as you use one for ssh; see the `interact` primitive in expect for the purpose).

Comment: Also, expect scripts are not shell scripts, so you're _already_ not using shell commands only; given that, the "shell commands only" specification is ambiguous if not contradictory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Good point about expect is technically not a shell command.

Answer (score 2):

My initial comment on your question noted that you should be looking into running expect locally and spawning ssh sessions to the remote servers.

While not exactly answering your question, here is a simple expect script that logs into a remote system (one of my systems at home named valhalla), uses `sudo -i` to become root and executes the `id` command to show the user UID/GIDs. Note that I use ssh keys for logins which is why there is no expect for the initial login password.

The remote systems do not need expect in this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# vi: set ts=2 sw=2 noai ic showmode showmatch: 

spawn ssh valhalla
expect "valhalla:"
send "sudo -i\r"
expect "assword for *"
send "XXXXXX\r"
expect "# "
send "id\r"
expect "(root)"
exit 0
```

Comment: Seriously though. Unless this was an assignment that required using expect, look at using https://www.ansible.com/. It is an awesome tool.

Comment: I don't agree that ansible is anything remotely like awesome (abuses YAML in a way that makes some reasonable values impossible to represent; missing major features found in competitors like Chef; slow-as-molasses performance), but it's surely far better than hand-written expect scripts. (At my current / soon-to-be-ex job, I ended up abandoning ansible in favor of rolling a purpose-built configuration management system on top of gomplate, integrated with systemd to allow just-in-time generation of templates before the services that depend on them start, and we're happier for it).

Comment: (mind, the other half of a two-person devops team I used to be part of went on to become CTO of Puppet Labs, whereas I swore off ever using the tool again, so this is all very much a place where reasonable minds can differ)

Comment: @Deathgrip thanks for your effort. I know it can be easily done with ansible but installing ansible on my local machine or remote server both not possible. That's why posted the question here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Awesome is a subjective term. We use Salt Stack for most things at my day job. But where a system is not yet salted, or some one-off task, I have found Ansible to be quite the timesaver. 
Rafailo - Ansible would only need to be installed locally and doesn't need to be installed by the root/superuser. Remote systems do require Python.

Comment: ...I don't seem to have written a public rant about the other place ansible's YAML use was causing problems, but https://serverfault.com/questions/584037/passing-free-form-commands-to-ansible-using-complex-args-form is another design oversight that's not dissimilar in form.